# Export datas from mongodb using mongoexport from a specific time range with query and timestamp

Tags: mongoexport

I'm trying to export a collection from mongodb using mongoexport. This works so far:

```
mongoexport.exe --db dataloggin --collection p1 --out myRecords.json
```

The problem is that the file is huge and I can not open it anymore (araound 20GB, 30 days, every half a second a document).

I just need the data between the 3. March and the 5 March, so I tried to select this date range with the query selector as following:

```
mongoexport.exe --db dataloggin --collection p1 -q='{"timestamp":{"$gte":{"$timestamp":"2016-03-3T00:00:00.000Z"}:},"timestamp":{"$lt":{"$timestamp":"2016-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"}}}' --out myRecords.json
```

But I get an error:

error validating settings: query '[39 123 116 105 109 101 115 116 97 109 112 58 123 36 103 116 101 58 123 36 116 105 109 101 115 116 97 109 112 58 50 48 49 54 45 48 49 45 48 49 84 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 46 48 48 48 90 125 58 125 44 116 105 109 101 115 116 97 109 112 58 123 36 108 116 58 123 36 116 105 109 101 115 116 97 109 112 58 50 48 49 54 45 48 49 45 48 49 84 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 46 48 48 48 90 125 125 125 39]' is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}

Someone have an idea?

Many Thanks and regards

Comment: Im using monogodb version 4.2

Comment: There is a stray ":" in the query here: `000Z"}:},`